# SAS is not properly updating

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I have a SAS script that copies data from a view, and saves them to a table. This includes a column that gives the date for when the view was last run (current_date AS sist_oppdatert).

I expected that whenever the SAS script is run, it will get fresh data from the view - with today as the date in column "sist_oppdatert".

This doesn't seem to be the case, as the "sist_oppdatert" column is not being updated. It shows an old date, and I then take it that the data I get are also outdated (haven't found a way to verify).
If I run the same SQL code manually directly in Teradata then everything works perfect. Not from SAS, not even with any sort of error. I need this to happen automatically.

So how can I make sure the table is updated daily, with the correct data and date?

SAS script:

```
proc sql;
connect to teradata 
(user="&user_id_td." password=&pwd. mode=teradata server=gjprodaz connection=global);
execute (
      delete from NL.KUB_2_kundedata_tbl
)
by teradata;
quit;

proc sql;
connect to teradata 
(user="&user_id_td." password=&pwd. mode=teradata server=gjprodaz connection=global);
execute (
    insert into NL.KUB_2_kundedata_tbl
    select distinct * from NL.KUB_2_kundedata
    ;
)
by teradata;
quit;
```

Comment: Not relevant, but remove the distinct from your select, that requires processing that is pointless.  As for your question, you are literally selecting everything from the source. Maybe the SAS script isn't running at the correct time (before the source has been updated), or it's not running at all, something along those lines.

Comment: This is odd.  Using this method, SAS isn't doing much work, just sending the code to teradata to execute.  So if it works in Teradata, it should work here.  If you run just the first step, did you confirm that it works? (i.e. successfully connects to teradata and deletes all the records from the table)

Comment: Issues seems to be with the definition of the view, not with this step. Can you confirm the view works on teradata as expected or share the view code to confirm it's correct.

Comment: In Oracle we need to sometimes submit a commit for the update to be refreshed. Not sure if Teradata has a similar command required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I realized I didn't have any proof that the scheduling was working at all.
I then noticed that the script was run through a different user.
I tried running the script with that user, and then it failed with "No more spool space".

So the whole problem was a property in the schedule user, being different from the manual user.